# Count unique values in row of datatable in R

Tags: r

I want to add an column to my datatable. The value of the added column should be the unique values of a few columns in this row. Something like:

```
avv <- avv %>% mutate (MMW_dist = n_distinct(MMW_01:MMW_12))
```

It produces this error

> Warning message in MMW_01:MMW_12: “numerical expression has 5484
>   elements: only the first used”

and all values in the columns `MMW_dist` are 1.

edit: Table looks like this (of course there are many more columns):

```
ID  Year    MMW_01  MMW_12
1   2012    0.1     0.2
1   2013    1.3     3.4
2   2012    0       0
3   2014    1.4     NA
```

Result should look like this (the distinct values in the row of columns MMW_01 to MMW_12):

```
ID  Year    MMW_01  MMW_12  MMW_dist
1   2012    0.1     0.2     2
1   2013    1.3     3.4     2
2   2012    0       0       1
3   2014    1.4     NA      1
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible dataset  [mre]; it probably only needs to be 2 or 3 rows by 3 or 4 columns with typical values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```r
avv <- avv %>% 
  mutate(MMW_dist = apply(select(., c(MMW_01:MMW_12)), 
                          1, 
                          function(x) n_distinct(x, na.rm = T)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way, to ignore (=not count) NA-values?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this:

```
avv <- avv %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(MMW_dist = n_distinct(MMW_01:MMW_12, na.rm = T))
```